# Why can't typescript recognise or type?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using `yargs` to parse the command line parameters. Below is the code:

```
import yargs from 'yargs';
import { hideBin } from 'yargs/helpers';
import { ArgType } from './types';

const argv = yargs(hideBin(process.argv))
  .option('migrateName', {
    alias: 'n',
    description: 'migration name',
    type: 'string',
  })
  .demandOption('migrateName')
  .help()
  .alias('help', 'h').parse();

console.log(argv.migrateName)
```

I got a compile error:

```
Property 'migrateName' does not exist on type '{ [x: string]: unknown; migrateName: string; _: (string | number)[]; $0: string; } | Promise<{ [x: string]: unknown; migrateName: string; _: (string | number)[]; $0: string; }>'.
  Property 'migrateName' does not exist on type 'Promise<{ [x: string]: unknown; migrateName: string; _: (string | number)[]; $0: string; }>'
```

it says `migrateName` doesn't exist on argv. But when looking at the `argv` type, it has an `or` operator. It's type is:

```
{
    [x: string]: unknown;
    migrateName: string;
    _: (string | number)[];
    $0: string;
} | Promise<{
    [x: string]: unknown;
    migrateName: string;
    _: (string | number)[];
    $0: string;
}>
```

I don't understand why `typescript` complains about this type even it already has `migrateName` in its type.

The version I am using is:

```
"@types/yargs": "^17.0.10",
"yargs": "^17.4.1",
"typescript": "^4.6.3"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use yargs's `parseSync()` function instead of `parse()` or put await in front of yargs, e.g., `const argv = await yargs(hideBin(process.argv))`.

TypeScript *is* actually describing the error, it's just a bit hard to read because there are some repeated types that have been expanded.

The entire error you have is this:

```
Property 'migrateName' does not exist on type '{ [x: string]: unknown; migrateName: string; _: (string | number)[]; $0: string; } | Promise<{ [x: string]: unknown; migrateName: string; _: (string | number)[]; $0: string; }>'.
  Property 'migrateName' does not exist on type 'Promise<{ [x: string]: unknown; migrateName: string; _: (string | number)[]; $0: string; }>'
```

If we look carefully, there are actually two lines to this error and a bunch of types that are repeated.

This type is repeated three times in the error message:

```
{ [x: string]: unknown; migrateName: string; _: (string | number)[]; $0: string; }
```

That looks like the CLI arguments you are trying to parse.

In our head, let's imagine that we have an alias for that type - let's call it `Arguments`.

If we use our imaginary `Arguments` type alias in that error message we get this:

```
Property 'migrateName' does not exist on type 'Arguments | Promise<Arguments>'.
  Property 'migrateName' does not exist on type 'Promise<Arguments>'
```

Now it's looking a bit clearer!

The yargs types say that the `parse()` function can return either the arguments themselves **or** a promise containing those arguments.

The TypeScript error is saying that you haven't handled all possible return types.
If a promise is returned then it won't have the `migrateName` property you are trying to access.

**Solution**

The simple fix is to use yargs's `parseSync()` function instead of `parse()`.

Comment: ...or put `await` in front of `yargs`.